# how to make <p> tag and <a> tag inside a <div> inline

Tags: html, css

I have [this html code](http://jsfiddle.net/prime/qA66e/)

As you can see the `<p>` tag element and the `<a>` tag element is not `inline`. `<a>` tag element is little bit higher than `<p>`.

Is there an easy way to make them **inline**. I can do it by changing **CSS**. But it is not neat i think.

Comment: You currently have both links inside individual divs. Your choices are to either remove the div's and use `<span>` around the text you want to align it, OR to style the test using CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting the padding and margin of your `<p>` and `<a>` tags, you will be sure that they will not use the inherited and default values. After that, you can simply make them float left and right. Here is the css:

```
#inboxHeader{
   background-color:yellow;
   overflow:hidden;
}
#inboxCount p, #inboxNewMessage a{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#inboxCount{
   float: left;
}
#inboxNewMessage{
   float: right;
}
```

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qA66e/9/)

Comment: but i want to be those to in the both corners. I mean `Visit W3Schools.com!` should be in the **right corner**

Comment: You are welcome! And I updated it one more time if you want it to have a height of 50px: http://jsfiddle.net/qA66e/10/

Comment: Thanks, it is perfect (Y)

Answer (score 2):

paragraphs has a default user agent stylesheet margin set:

```
p {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

just add a

```
p, a {
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}
```

this way you can set their margins together, or define a default for your paragraph

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `margin:0` on the `p` inside the `div`. This is added by default by the browser. Then use `line-height` to give it the vertical alignment you'd like.

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qA66e/11/).